# Laravel query builder GROUP BY method alongside with SKIP and TAKE methods

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-5.7, laravel-query-builder, skip-take

I have around 50000 records and I am showing them in Datatable with server side processing.
In my query I am applying the `groupBy()` method with `skip()` and `take()` method.

I want to be able to apply the limit **AFTER** `groupBy()` e.g.

If limit is 10 it should return 10 groups not 10 records.

```
DB::table('actions')->whereBetween('timestamp', 
array($dates['startDate'], $dates['endDate']))
->where('shop_name', $shopName)
->skip($start)
->take(10)
->get()
->groupBy('product_id');
```

With this query i am getting 10 records not 10 groups.

Comment: Put your `groupBy()` before your `->get()`

Comment: i have tried then groupBY() doesn't work.It shows 10 records without groups.

Comment: Does it show 10 different actions with 10 different product_id's? Since that's what you're grouping by. You **HAVE** to put your groupBy() before your get().

Comment: yes it shows 10 different actions with 10 different product_id's.

Comment: Then it worked, you have 10 different groups, because you have more than 10+ product_id's, you'll receive 10 records. It did exactly what you asked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::table('actions')
            ->whereBetween('timestamp', array($dates['startDate'], $dates['endDate']))
            ->where('shop_name', $shopName)
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('product_id')
            ->splice($start,$rowperpage);
```

and this order worked.

Comment: While this will *work*, you are performing the splicing operations after you fetched `50,000` records. It's no an ideal case from a memory perspective. I edited my answer to include an `offset()` statement. You could use that to offset your query if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting `take(10)` and adding `limit(10)` at the very end of your query but before `get()`.

Comment: I tried its not returning 10 groups .it return 3 groups with 10 records

Answer (score 0):

The order of your query statements are wrong. The following should do the trick. Notice the `groupBy()` is before your `take()` and `get()`.

In your case, you are grouping after the records have been fetched.

```
DB::table('actions')
    ->whereBetween('timestamp', array($dates['startDate'], $dates['endDate']))
    ->where('shop_name', $shopName)
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->skip($start)
    ->take(10)
    ->get()
```

Comment: You can also use `->limit(10)` over `->take(10)`. Take is an alias of limit. This is the correct answer. *thumbs up*

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote/mark this as the answer if it worked for you. See [What should I do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Mozammil which is the best approach splice() method or the take and skip methods?

Comment: There's no splice method. The alias to `take()` is `limit()`. It's just a matter of personal choice. They both do the same thing :)

Comment: Their is a splice method i have tried this after group by and it also worked like a charm  'splice($start,$rowperpage)'

Comment: [Splice](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_splice) is a Collection method. Not one available in the QueryBuilder. For this particular case, I'd rather use `take()` or `limit()`